# Latex Itemization

Tags: latex, enumerate

How can I edit the **enumerate command** in **latex** such that when I type \item it shows item list like this

```
[1] Line 1
[2] Line 2
```

Comment: This question is not appropriate for SO. It should be asked on TeX SE instead.

Comment: Nick is right, but since we are all contributing ...hey what the heck:   https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2291/how-do-i-change-the-enumerate-list-format-to-use-letters-instead-of-the-defaul

Answer (score 1):

Use [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) to change the `label` representation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={[\arabic*]}]
  \item Line 1
  \item Line 2
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```